# Should I use urandom() or openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()?

Tags: hash, php, random, salt

I am developing a site in PHP 5.4. Which function is better to use to generate a random salt for password security?

```
$salt = sha1(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(23));
```

or

```
$seed = '';
$a = @fopen('/dev/urandom','rb');
$seed .= @fread($a,23);
$salt = sha1(seed);
```

Or should I just go with:

```
$salt =  openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(40);
```

or

```
$salt = '';
$a = @fopen('/dev/urandom','rb');
$salt .= @fread($a,23);
```

Comment: [Oh You!](http://i.stack.imgur.com/RPMRb.jpg) [Don't be Dave.](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/25585/is-my-developers-home-brew-password-security-right-or-wrong-and-why)

Comment: Salts don't need great quality randomness. Being unique is enough.

Comment: Rather than hashing the output of the openssl function you'd be better off using bin2hex if you need a string: $salt = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(64));

Comment: @TomJowitt  $salt = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32)); for 64 char length!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The right way to generate a salt for password hashing is: do not do it yourself. Use a library which already does thing properly. See @Terry's answer for pointers.

For your exact question, it so happens that `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()` relies on OpenSSL's internal [PRNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator), which itself feeds on what the underlying platform provides, i.e. `dev/urandom`, so it is safe. Strictly speaking, you should use the second parameter of that function to check whether OpenSSL *did* find a strong source of randomness on the local platform (see [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php)), but in practice, as long as OpenSSL runs on a Unix-like or Windows-like platform, things will be fine. So it does not really matter, for security, whether you call `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()` or read `/dev/urandom` yourself. For maintenance reasons, I would prefer the former, which is simpler (only one call) and more portable (it will also work on Windows, whereas reading `/dev/urandom` will not).

Either way, applying SHA-1 on the output of `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()` or `/dev/urandom`, is totally useless. Good PRNG already produce unpredictable uniformly random bytes (and if your PRNG is not good, then why are you using it ?).

Comment: He might be using the hash function to convert binary output  into human readable encoding. bin2hex() PHP function could be used to achieve the same, without hashing the output.

Comment: doesnt have to be readable and thank you, and i was aware of of the second second parameter and had used it to test my system to see if it had enough randomness and entropy, i scoured the doc pages on both before i asked the question, i am writing this more to advance my knowledge than i am to do production development.

Comment: as a learning developer i feel that i should thoroughly explore the code i am learning, to give me a better grasp of it and what it does. so down the road when i am using libraries like phpass i will have a better command of what they are doing to handle debugging, and many other thing, what i learn doing this could lead to learning any number of other things.

Answer (score 3):

**Note:** This doesn't answer the question exactly.

Try not to roll your own crypto. Since you are using PHP, a great bcrypt library - [phpass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/), is readily available that will take care of the password hashing aspect, including generating salts.

Comment: PHP's new [password-related functions](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/password_hash) are also worth a look. They'll be available from 5.5, in the meantime there's a [compatibility lib](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).