# Use brute force to mitigate brute force

Tags: passwords, hash, brute-force

Just an idea I had, and I am sure there is a lot of material about this subject, so I am looking for a pointer as to where I can find more information.

My idea is this...

When storing a password in a database, it is common to store it as a hash. This is weak against rainbow tables, which is mitigated by adding salt, and is also weak against brute force attacks.

I am thinking that it is possible to store the hash, modified with a small random string...

Using md5

```
mypass -> 2b643a4d56186389d84dbb3a9a483e99
```

If you have the hash, the password can be found by simply hashing all possible passwords, and comparing the hash, so...

```
// append a random 3 character string of a-z characters, we can use "xth" for this example
mypassxth -> 02a2247c788681af6ce1bb5fa66dd4c0
```

The random string is never stored, never shared, and only resides in memory on the server at the time of storing the hash.

This makes lookup of passwords less efficient, because the server must check any incoming requests by brute forcing the partly complete input against the stored hash, which in this case would mean an upper bound of 17576 (26^3) checks to validate the password.

It would also make brute force attack much harder in this case, an upper bound (assuming a-z only) of 5429503678976 (26^9) rather than 308915776 (26^6).

I guess it is like using a very small salt, that is not stored anywhere, requiring brute forcing during lookup operations.

Assuming I am not completely missing something obvious that makes this not work, can someone tell me what this concept is called, or point me somewhere where I can read about it?

Comment: The problem with your code is that your server-side brute force function needs somewhere between 1 and 17576 iterations to exit successfully (has variable cost). This is not anything like how some inherently slow KDFs that @TerryChia mentioned in his answer function, by introducing a known and non-variable cost to using them.

Comment: While @TildalWave is certainly right, it _is_ a useful evasion technique used by malware, since the key will be nowhere in the binary itself.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Seriously, don't be a [Dave](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/25585/10211) and roll your own crypto.

Use a proven KDF such as `PBKFD2`, `bcrypt` or `scrypt` to hash your passwords. See this [great answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/31846/10211) for more information on how to securely hash passwords.

For your scheme, `mypass` is essentially no longer your password. `mypassxth` is. An attacker has no problems just bruteforcing the password with his nice little GPU as you are using `MD5`. This has NO bearing on an attackers ability to bruteforce your password, and just makes password hashing that much more computationally expensive for your servers.

If you are using a good KDF like `bcrypt` instead of `MD5` for password hashing, this scheme will add **a lot** of additional load on your servers with very little gain.

Comment: Well, the password is no longer `mypass` and becomes `mypassxth` - which is the point - to make a stringer password, which is still usable. People prefer to have a shorter password, like 8 characters, and if the system can make it as string as an 11 character password, surely that is a good thing no? As far as I can tell, it does have a bearing on the attacker's ability to brute force it, because it increases the length of the password, which makes it harder to brute force. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: it seems that `bcrypt` and `scrypt` are solving the same problem space, but much more efficiently, and with more concerns thought out. Thanks for the links - I am learning. (not implementing any of my own crypto, just trying to understand more about it).