# End-to-end WhatsApp vs Telegram

Tags: encryption, instant-messaging, whatsapp

What do you think about the latest WhatsApp update?
Is now WhatsApp as secure as Telegram?
Which one should be trusted?
Which one has the strongest and most secure encryption?

Comment: Drop Telegram and use Signal! Telegram is some home-brewn crypto with a marketing department while Signal has excellent crypto with open source and a rather mediocre marketing department.

Comment: @SEJPM wish I could upvote your comment 1000000 times.

Comment: End of discussion, already established here with the latest comments and posts that if you choose Telegram, you might deserve it => http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/49782/is-telegram-secure?rq=1

Comment: "Drop Telegram and use Signal! Telegram is some home-brewn crypto with a marketing department while Signal has excellent crypto with open source and a rather mediocre marketing department. " <-- if they would only release a desktop and a web client..
Or do they expect that all the world should use mobile devices to communicate?????

Comment: @Paul, Signal *does* have a [web client](https://whispersystems.org/blog/signal-desktop/).

Comment: I can't see it.. you linked "signal desktop"

Comment: Weren't WhatsApp using the same tech from Signal?

Comment: @SEJPM Well, the web client of Signal requires first compulsorily installing the app on the phone, right? That's a deal-breaker for me. They should not force people to install the app on the phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a job for your eyes! Read the terms and conditions and see if they mention anything about your data in there. Remember YOU are using THEIR service, which means YOU have NO CONTROL over what you put on their service.

Realistically though it sounds like it's in their best interest to keep your private stuff private since it's easier on them, easier on you, and safer for both parties.

However without checking the ToS of both apps in depth you can't really know for sure. This at best is no more secure than encrypted email services, and at worse is not secure but that is the nature of using someone else's encryption service and not your own.