# Is Telegram now secure enough to consider?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, instant-messaging

Though there have been similar questions left stagnant over the years, this seems relevant with news of [WhatsApp](http://whatsapp.com) [privacy policy changes](http://thehackernews.com/2016/08/facebook-whatsapp.html).

**Has [Telegram](https://telegram.org/) made serious improvements to issues like [dangerous defaults](https://twitter.com/snowden/status/678271881242374144?lang=en) and [rolling their own crypto](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/1177.pdf) to be worth seriously considering?**

Answer (score 0):

This has already been answered and recently updated (as of yesterday).

[Is Telegram E2E Still Insecure?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/130559/is-telegram-e2e-still-insecure/130579#130579)