# What does Telegram store (or potentially forward to 3rd parties)?

Tags: logging, instant-messaging, telegram

The Telegram messaging application apparently stores messages on its servers (at least - that's what it says in answers to [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/49782/is-telegram-secure?r=SearchResults&s=3%7C48.7031) here on the site). Is that everything it stores or forwards to a third party? Let me be more specific. Does Telegram store or forward...

1. Messages in groups?
2. Messages in bi-partisan chats?
3. Bi-partisan audio conversation meta-data?
4. Bi-partisan audio conversation contents?
5. Content which has been changed by edit, or deleted?
6. Search terms?
7. Keystrokes?
8. Anything else?

If there's storage in encrypted form for which only the end-user has the key - please mention that.

Comment: This is more of a question for the vendor. They are the ones who will know.

Comment: In fact, they cover most of this on their site: https://telegram.org/privacy

Comment: @schroeder: But 1. Can I believe what they say? And 2. Some of the wording is weasely, e.g. "We do not store your secret chats on our servers" <- but that doesn't say they don't store it elsewhere, nor that they don't send a copy to a third party.

Comment: If you cannot believe what *they* say, how will we know what is true?

Comment: @schroeder: 1. I understand that their client is FOSS, so we can know what's being sent (e.g. keystrokes). 2. Circumstancial evidence 3. Insider information. I was hoping people on this site would be more knowledgable in one of those avenues.

Comment: 1. we can know what is sent but not what is processed, 2 pure opinion, 3. insiders would be bound by NDA and so would have to couch as opinion (see #2)

Comment: 1. If it's sent it's likely at least processed. 2. No, those can be somewhat conclusive. If some information got out which can be traced back to a Telegram exchange, then we know that leaks somehow (think: The Enigma dilemma) 3. Maybe not all of it is a secret; and if it is, there are sometimes whistleblowers.